# Cannot invoke 'perform' with an argument list of type '(_)'

Tags: swift, xcode, square-connect

Why is this Square example straight for their README not working?

```
    let callbackURL = URL(string: "OdinMobile://")!
    do {
        let amount = try SCCMoney(amountCents: money, currencyCode: "USD")

        let request : SCCAPIRequest =
            try SCCAPIRequest(
                callbackURL: callbackURL,
                amount: amount,
                userInfoString: userInfoString,
                merchantID: nil,
                notes: notes,
                customerID: nil,
                supportedTenderTypes: supportedTenderTypes,
                clearsDefaultFees: clearsDefaultFees,
                returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment: true
            )

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    do {
        try SCCAPIConnection.perform(request)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

I get a `Cannot invoke 'perform' with an argument list of type '(_)'` with an additional message of `Overloads for 'perform' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (SCCAPIRequest), (Selector!)`. I'd like for `request` to be a SCCAPIRequest, why isn't it reading as one? Is it because it is in a `do` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `do` keyword creates a scope inside of its curly braces, like an `if` or `for` loop, meaning the request you create is inside the first scope and not available in the second. Since in both cases you're doing the same thing with the same error, you can just move the `perform` call inside the same scope.

```
let callbackURL = URL(string: "OdinMobile://")!
do {
    let amount = try SCCMoney(amountCents: money, currencyCode: "USD")

    let request : SCCAPIRequest =
        try SCCAPIRequest(
            callbackURL: callbackURL,
            amount: amount,
            userInfoString: userInfoString,
            merchantID: nil,
            notes: notes,
            customerID: nil,
            supportedTenderTypes: supportedTenderTypes,
            clearsDefaultFees: clearsDefaultFees,
            returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment: true
        )
    try SCCAPIConnection.perform(request)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: @NilsGuillermin Please be sure to accept this answer when you get a chance... thanks mate!